# Why am I getting a "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.String" error here?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using android with kotlin and I am getting this error.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String in line 60

I don't see why it thinks there is a `Float`, to begin with. Here is line 60:

```
val bal:String = sp.getString("Balance", "0.00")!!.toString()
```

where sp is an instance of `SharedPreferences`.

Here is my full code:

```
package com.applications.darshan.piggybank

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var balance : TextView ?= null
private var amount : EditText ?= null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    balance = findViewById(R.id.balance)
    amount = findViewById(R.id.amount)
    var sp:SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Balance", 0)
    addZero()
    balance!!.text = "Your balance is $" + sp.getString("Balance", "0.00")

}
fun onClick(v: View){
    var addAmount:Float ?
    try{
        addAmount = amount!!.text.toString().toFloat()
    }catch(e:Exception){
        addAmount = 0.00f
    }

    var sp:SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Balance", 0)
    val editor = sp.edit()
    var amountNum = sp.getString("Balance", "0.00").toFloat()
    when(v.id.toString()){
        "2131165209" -> amountNum += addAmount!!
        "2131165314" -> amountNum -= addAmount!!
    }
    editor.putString("Balance", amountNum.toString())
    editor.apply()
    editor.commit()
    addZero()
    balance!!.text = "Your balance is $" + sp.getString("Balance", "0.00")

}
fun clearBalance(v:View){
    var sp:SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Balance", 0)
    val editor = sp.edit()
    editor.putString("Balance",  "0.00")
    editor.apply()
    editor.commit()
    addZero()
    balance!!.text = "Your balance is $" + sp.getString("Balance", "0.00")
    addZero()

}
fun addZero(){
    val sp:SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("Balance", 0)
    val bal:String = sp.getString("Balance", "0.00")!!.toString()
    val editor = sp.edit()
    val balLen = bal.length
    val dot:Char = bal[balLen-2]
    if(dot.equals('.')){
        System.out.println(true)
        var x:String = bal + "0"
        editor.putString("Balance", x)
        System.out.println(x)
        editor.apply()
        editor.commit()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have inserted into `SharedPreferences` `float` and getting `String`. You will have to get a `float` from `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a float from you sp and cast it to String after

```
val bal:String = Float.toString(sp.getFloat("Balance", 0.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this following, which will typeCast into `Float`

```
Float.valueOf(sp.getString("Balance", "0.00"));
```

Comment: I want it to be a string not a float

Comment: @DarshanKrishnaswamy, Well you have inserted `float` value into `String` in `SharedPreference` here  `var amountNum = sp.getString("Balance", "0.00").toFloat()` then `editor.putString("Balance", amountNum.toString())` according to that you will have to get `String` from `SharedPreference` then have to typeCast into `float` like in this answer